# Edit a registry of a not currently running Windows system for P2V

Tags: windows, images, virtualization

I want to virtualize an existing Windows XP machine. (in VirtualBox, or in Virtual PC if the first doesn't work)...

I made an image of this machine's HD without running the MergeIDE tool before.

When I give this image to VirtualBox or Virtual PC : it is unable to boot Windows XP properly i'm getting a blue screen of death!

(In order to make Windows inspecting the Virtual Box HD : I need to run patch the registry with the MergeIDE tool)

I'm able to mount the virtual disk image on my host system. Is there any way to modify the register of this system (by accessing to RAW register file with a specific tool ?)

I want to do this instead of making again an image of the real Windows. Moreover, I'm not sure if I'll not get a BSOD even after having patched the registry..

Answer (score 1):

The Registry Editor built in to Windows allows loading "Hives" from the other users or machines for editing.  This option is in on File > Load Hive.

Registry files for the whole system are stored in

```
C:\windows\system32\config
```

and user files are in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\ntuser.dat
```

Comment: Also `reg load`.